# Querying Nested JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some JSON data that's formatted like this:

```
{
    "id": "ABC123",
    "offerPrice": 42.00,
    "regularPrice": 42.00,
    "variations": [{
        "key": "Style",
        "value": "Black"
    }, {
        "key": "Personalization",
        "value": "2 Lines of Personalization"
    }]
}, {
    "id": "987ZYX",
    "offerPrice": 52.00,
    "regularPrice": 52.00,
    "variations": [{
        "key": "Style",
        "value": "Black"
    }, {
        "key": "Personalization",
        "value": "3 Lines of Personalization"
    }]
}
```

What I need to do is query for values inside of the 'variations' array and return the object if a match is found.

I'm able to query the 'first level' of values just fine:

```
var results = jQuery.grep(obj, function (element, index) {
    return element.offerPrice == "42.00";
});
```

and I can query for variations if I specify an index value (which I obviously don't want to do):

```
var results = jQuery.grep(obj, function (element, index) {
    return element.variations[1].key == "Personalization" && element.variations[1].value == "2 Lines of Personalization";
});
```

This is ideally what I want to do, but it doesn't work:

```
var results = jQuery.grep(obj.variations, function (element, index) {
    return element.key == "Personalization" && element.value == "2 Lines of Personalization";
});
```

I keep getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Here's a jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/VzqWW/3/

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll nee dto use .grep twice.

Comment: what is the structure that you're expecting to output?

Comment: I thought I was getting somewhere with nested greps but this returns all of your objects http://jsfiddle.net/59RGE/ (sorry to be so unhelpful - have been called away but thought my ham-fisted attempt might give you a clue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such object as `obj.variations` since obj is an array.
Something like that should work:

```
var results = jQuery.grep(obj, function (element, index) {
    res = jQuery.grep(element.variations, function (element2, index2) {
        return element2.key== "Personalization" && element2.value == "2 Lines of Personalization";
    });
    return (res.length != 0);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tomer! I ended up using this solution because it works well and doesn't require any ES5 shims. We definitely support browsers < IE9 so this seemed to be the best option for us.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with standard array filtering with the `map` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)), `reduce` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce%5d)) and `filter`([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) methods that came as part of ES5, I've updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qBzQe/1/) to use them but the code is inline below:

```
var variations = obj.map(function (x) { 
    return x.variations;
}).reduce(function (x, y) {
   return x.concat(y); 
});

var personalizationVariations = variations.filter(function (v) {
    return v.key== "Personalization" && v.value == "2 Lines of Personalization"
});
console.log('Personalization Variations', personalizationVariations);
```

If you're supporting ES3 browsers (< IE9) you'll need something like [es5shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) which adds these methods.

Answer (score 1):

How about this using [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) along with grep.

```
var allVariations = $.map(obj, function(element, i) {
    return element.variations;
});

var variations = $.grep(allVariations, function(variation, index) {
    return variation.key == "Personalization" && variation.value == "2 Lines of Personalization";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
var obj=[{
    "id": "ABC123",
    "offerPrice": 42.00,
    "regularPrice": 42.00,
    "variations": [{
        "key": "Style",
        "value": "Black"
    }, {
        "key": "Personalization",
        "value": "2 Lines of Personalization"
    }]
}, {
    "id": "987ZYX",
    "offerPrice": 52.00,
    "regularPrice": 52.00,
    "variations": [{
        "key": "Style",
        "value": "Black"
    }, {
        "key": "Personalization",
        "value": "3 Lines of Personalization"
    }]
}];
var result=$.grep(obj,function(element,index){
    return element.offerPrice=="42.00";
});
var variations=$.grep(result[0].variations, function(element, index){
    return element.key == "Personalization" && element.value == "2 Lines of Personalization";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES5 you can write something like that:

```
var filtered = obj.filter(function(el){
  return el.variations.some(function(el) {
    return el.key === "Personalization" && el.value === "2 Lines of Personalization";
  })
});

console.log(filtered);
```

You can use `grep` in jQuery to simulate `filter`, but as far as I know, it doesn't have anything like `some`. Of course you can emulate it. You can also find shim of [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in MDN.

In general, it's always good have a shim for ES5 function, if we want to support older browsers.